# Sync mechanism to azure search - How Reliable is azure search insertion?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-cognitive-search, reliability, azure-search-.net-sdk

How reliable is the insertion mechanism to azure search?

Say, a call on average to upload to azure search. Are there any slas on this? average insertion time for one document, average failure rate for one document.

I'm trying to send data from my database to azure search and I was wondering if it was more reliable to send data directly to azure search, or do a dual write for example to a high available queue like kafka and read from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [SLA for Azure Search](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/search/v1_0/):

> We guarantee at least 99.9% availability for index query requests when
>   an Azure Search Service Instance is configured with two or more
>   replicas, and index update requests when an Azure Search Service
>   Instance is configured with three or more replicas. No SLA is provided
>   for the Free tier.

Your client code needs to follow the best practices: batch indexing requests, retry on transient failures with an exponential back-off policy, and scale service appropriately based on the size of the documents and indexing load.

Whether or not use an intermediate buffer depends not so much on SLA, but how spiky your indexing load will be, and how decoupled you want your search indexing component to be.

You may also find [Capacity planning for Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-capacity-planning) useful.